# OpenApi Swagger3 default clientId and Password

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger, openapi

I'm using @SecurityScheme annotation in my Spring boot application. It works fine, I can authenticate via open api and call endpoints via Swagger, but I want to have default clientId/password, so consumers would not need to type it.

```
@SecurityScheme(name ="oauth2", 
                type = SecuritySchemeType.OAUTH2,
                flows = @OAuthFlows(clientCredentials = @OAuthFlow(tokenUrl = "https://someurl/token")))
```

Therefore, is it possible to add default credentials for the OpenApi calls?

Answer (score 1):

put this on your boostrap or yml file and will work:

```html
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    oauth:
      clientId: 'clientDefault'
```

inside the clientId value, you can put your own clientId default. Do the same for password.